# Prove that $f$ where $|f(z)| \leq |f(\frac{z}{2})| + \frac{1}{2^n} $ is a constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Here is the question I want to solve:

Let $f$ be an entire function and assume that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $$|f(z)| \leq |f(\frac{z}{2})| + \frac{1}{2^n} \text{ if } 2^n \leq |z| \leq 2^{n+1}.$$
Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Here is a solution given to me that I do not know if is correct or not:

> [image]

1- Is this solution correct?

2- Also, actually, I do not see why the step before last implies the last step i.e., why the author is claiming that $|f(\frac{z}{2^{n +1}})|$ should be less that or equal some constant $M$?

Can someone help me answer these questions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is correct
2. The answer are the two first lines of the proof. Since $f$ (is entire, in particular) is continuous. Using this and the fact that $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z| \leq 1\}$ is compact, then $|f|$ attains it maximum in that set. Then, you can take $M$ as any constant bigger or equal that this maximum. Finally, since $2^{n} \leq |z| \leq z^{n+1}$ then $\frac{z}{2^{n+1}} \in D$: $|\frac{z}{2^{n+1}}| =\frac{|z|}{2^{n+1}} \leq \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}=1$. Since $|f(w)| \leq M$ for all $w \in D$, in particular this is true for $w=\frac{z}{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: Why the author is using $f(\frac{z}{2})$ then $f(\frac{z}{4})$ then $f(\frac{z}{8})$ and so on?

Comment: Also, Liouville's theorem says that If $f$ is a bounded entire function then $f$ is constant. So, can we say then $f$ is constant without using the given assumption that $|f(z)| \leq |f(\frac{z}{2})| + \frac{1}{2^n},$ ? I actually do not see the importance of this assumption if we already know that the function $f$ is bounded on the unit disk, could you clarify this please?

Comment: I also do not understand why is the first inequality in the solution I gave in my question is less than the second inequality ..... could you clarify please?

Comment: 1. To obtain a global bound for $f$. 2 No, you need some asumption to obtain a global bound. Otherwise, you only know that $f$ is bounded on the unit disk, but it can be unbounded outside. 3 You have to use the given bound: call $w=z/2$, since $2^{n} \leq |z| \leq 2^{n+1}$, then $2^{n-1} \leq |w| \leq 2^{n}$, then $f(w)\leq |f(w/2)|+1/2^{n-1}$. Thus, $|f(z/2)|+1/2^{n}  = |f(w)|+1/2^{n} \leq |f(w/2)|+1/2^{n-1}+1/2^{n}=|f(z/4)| +1/2^{n-1}+1/2^{n}$.